# Transformar JsonObject em JsonArray

Tags: android, json

Como pego o dados desse Json? Quero transformar em um JsonArray para poder percorrer, mas ele é um JsonObject...

```
{
  "1":{"a":"1","c":"0","d":"0","m":"0","ns":"0","proc":"0"},   
  "2":{"a":"1","c":"0","d":"0","m":"0","ns":"0","proc":"0"},  
  "3":{"a":"1","c":"0","d":"0","m":"0","ns":"0","proc":"0"},    
  "4":{"a":"1","c":"0","d":"0","m":"0","ns":"0","proc":"0"},   
  "5":{"a":"1","c":"0","d":"0","m":"0","ns":"0","proc":"0"}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, você já tem esse JSON e quer 'transformar' ele de `JSONObject` pra `JSONArray`.

Seguindo, pode ser feito da seguinte forma.

```
JSONObject json; // <- O seu JSONObject
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(); // JSONArray com os objetos
for(int i = 1; i <= json.lenght(); i++) {
    array.put(json.getJSONObject(""+i));
}
```

O seu `JSONArray` resultante será algo parecido com esse:

```
[
    {"a":1,"c":0,"d":0,"m":0,"ns":0,"proc":0},
    {"a":1,"c":0,"d":0,"m":0,"ns":0,"proc":0},
    {"a":1,"c":0,"d":0,"m":0,"ns":0,"proc":0}
]
```

Comment: muito obrigado consegui

Comment: Sem problemas, agradeço se marcar ela como correta.

Comment: Apenas atente-se de que esse formato só irá funcionar se as chaves do JSONObject forem números, sequenciais e iniciados em 1. `for(int i = 1; i <= json.lenght(); i++) {
    array.put(json.getJSONObject(""+i));
}`

Comment: sim sim... muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("my json");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("1");
jsonArray.getString(0);// 1
```

Teste com o seu json e veja se a saida vai ser 1.
Espero que ajude

Comment: pior q não funcionou não sei o porque mais obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: talvez sua notação de array esteja incorreta o correto seria []. De uma olhada neste link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: consegui agora obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar um JSONObject em JSONArray você terá que percorrer todas as chaves e ir adicionando os filhos no JSONArray.

Dessa forma:

> {"1":{"a":1,"c":0},"2":{"a":1,"c":0},"3":{"a":1,"c":0}} // JSONObject que será tranformado

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("1", new JSONObject() {{
    put("a", 1);
    put("c", 0);
}});
json.put("2", new JSONObject() {{
    put("a", 1);
    put("c", 0);
}});
json.put("3", new JSONObject() {{
    put("a", 1);
    put("c", 0);
}});

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

// Percorre as chaves do JSONObject e vai adicionando os filhos no JSONArray.
for (String key : JSONObject.getNames(json)) {
    jsonArray.put(json.getJSONObject(key));
}

// Exibe o conteúdo do jsonArray
System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

A primeira etapa é montar o JSONObject. *Como você já tem ele, não precisará fazer isso.* Em seguida, declaro o JSONArray. Por fim, percorro as chaves do JSONObject adicionando os seus filhos no JSONArray.

Ao final você terá o seu JSONArray da seguinte forma:

> [{"a":1,"c":0},{"a":1,"c":0},{"a":1,"c":0}]

Comment: muito obrigado consegui